# Hibernate 6/Spring Boot 3 - Wrong generated SQL for pagable native query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm migrating a project to Spring Boot 3 (Hibernate 6). The following native query is pageable (query simplyfied to reproduce the problem):

```java
`    @Query(
            value = """
                    select s.id as id, s.name as name, gp.points
                    from specialist s
                    left join (select q.specialist_id, listagg(q.points, ';') as points from qualification q group by q.specialist_id) gp on gp.specialist_id = s.id
                    where name like :name
                    """
            , nativeQuery = true)
    Page<SpecialistOverview> overview(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);`
```

The Hibernate generated SQL is this:

```sql
select s.id as id, s.name as name, gp.points
from specialist s
         left join (select q.specialist_id, listagg(q.points, ' fetch first ? rows only;') as points
                    from qualification q
                    group by q.specialist_id) gp on gp.specialist_id = s.id
where name like ?
order by name asc
```

As you can see the "fetch first ? rows only" part is now part of the delimiter literal of the listagg function. When executing this query, it will result in a DataIntegrityViolationException complaining about parameter mismatch (the second ? is part of the literal).

Running on Spring Boot 3.0.4 (Hibernate 6.1.7.Final).

With Spring Boot 2.7.9 (Hibernate 5.6.15.Final) everything is fine:

```sql
select s.id as id, s.name as name, gp.points
from specialist s
         left join (select q.specialist_id, listagg(q.points, ';') as points
                    from qualification q
                    group by q.specialist_id) gp on gp.specialist_id = s.id
where name like ?
order by name asc
limit ?
```

Before opening an Hibernate issue I will ask here. I expect working generated sql code (as under Hibernate 5.6.x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this as a bug in Spring Boot JPA and it has been fixed.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2884 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/2891 for details.